# Persist Object with collections in Hbase witth DataNucleus+JPA

Tags: jpa, hbase, datanucleus

I´m using DataNucleus and JPA to persit objects in Hbase.

I have 2 classes

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@IdClass(ComposedIdKey.class)
@Table(name="bolha")
public class Customer_test2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "data:_firstName")
    public String firstName;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "data:_lastName")
    public String lastName;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "data:_dateOfBirth")
    public String dateOfBirth;

    @Basic
    @Lob
    @Column(name="data:Telephones")
    public List<TelephoneNumber> telephones;

    public Customer_test2() {
    }
```

**and**

```
public class TelephoneNumber implements Serializable  {

 public CharSequence phoneType;
 public CharSequence phone;


  public TelephoneNumber() {}
```

when i persist the object, gives this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family bolha does not exist in region bolha,,1462285108381.a5453201be241f6601cfdb2714b802ea. in table 'bolha',
```

But the column exists. Any help

Comment: Decide which API you're using first. I'm sure DataNucleus documentation would say what is supported for a database, something like http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/datastores/datastore_features.html

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton . 
My choice is DataNucleus, because it supports Serialised Collection for Hbase. But I can not find a structure that works.

I tested this (seen in DataNucleus documentation.
aBasic
    aLob
    aColumn(name="data:Telephones")
    public List<TelephoneNumber> telephones;                                                                                                   but give a error

Comment: "It gives an error" ... what do you expect someone to do when they can't see the "error" ? why not create a question with a specific problem, input, mapping info, and WHAT THE ERROR is?

Comment: @NeilStockton. you have reason, but the error gave me now was just to share with you. I'll rephrase the question. Thanks

Comment: I've serialised fields with HBase so you have to debug your problem, using the log - why is HBase/Hadoop objecting to your column family ... ought to be simple enough to see why that columnfamily doesn't exist. You could also use an AttributeConverter for the field, defining how to persist a Collection of TelephoneNumber into a single field.

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton

Comment: @NeilStockton the column family exists. If a remove the annotations from public List<TelephoneNumber> telephones it´s work for the others parameters. I implements a serialized in the two class. what could be wrong?

Comment: If the "column family exists" then it wont throw an exception with that message. The LOG tells you what is happening, what is put to the database, what is GET from the database. That ought to be step 1 in debugging

Comment: @NeilStockton log  PUT into HBase table "bolha" as {"totalColumns":6,"row":"02-01-2010MariaMede","families":{"bolha":[{"qualifier":"telephones","vlen":170,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807},{"qualifier":"hitsAvailability","vlen":1,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223372036854775807}],"data":[{"qualifier":"_lastName","vlen":4,"tag":[],"timestamp":92237},{"qualifier":"InternalIdentifier","vlen":2,"tag":[],"timestamp":9223},{"qualifier":"_firstName","vlen":5,"tag":[],"timestamp":9227},{"qualifier":"_dateOfBirth","vlen":10,"tag":[],"timestamp":97}]}}
Exception thrown on insert